# Missing header when decoding mp3 file with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

When I used [AndroidFFmpeg](https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg) to play audio file (MP3 file),  I got issue

> header missing while seeking.

Video play is ok; error occurs only in mp3 file.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a temporary solution to fix it. In mpegaudiodec.c, you comment out errors return:

```
header = AV_RB32(buf);

if (header>>8 == AV_RB32("TAG")>>8) {
    av_log(avctx, AV_LOG_DEBUG, "discarding ID3 tag\n");
    return buf_size;
}
if (ff_mpa_check_header(header) < 0) {
    av_log(avctx, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Header missing\n");
    //return AVERROR_INVALIDDATA; do not return errors
}
```